# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level, although the indentation looks correct

Tags: python, indentation, python-2.x

When I compile the Python code below, I get

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

---

```
import sys

def Factorial(n): # Return factorial
    result = 1
    for i in range (1,n):
        result = result * i
    print "factorial is ",result
    return result
```

Why?

Comment: I had the same error, but I happened to indent a method *way up* in the code slightly to the left, which gave this error at the bottom of the *next* method after it. So this error can occur not only from mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: I am using Sublime Text 3. I have a Django project. I fixed the error using `View > Indentation > Intent Using Spaces`

Comment: I found using IDLE makes it much easier to find indentation issues. It will clearly find indentation errors that most editors wont find.

Comment: I am using Sublime Text 3 with a Flask project. I fixed the error using `View > Indentation > Tab Width: 4` after unselected `Indent Using Spaces`.

Comment: Sublime 3.2.2 : View > Indentation > Convert Indentation to Spaces -- worked for me

Comment: running ``dos2unix *`` helped in my case

Comment: You can see the problem by looking at the [Markdown source](/revisions/96e24cec-7518-41c7-ba3e-362a85393b3c/view-source): You have tabs preceding the last three lines. Stack Overflow unfortunately converts tabs to 4 spaces on rendering, so the issue disappears.

Answer (score 856, accepted):

One possible cause for this error is that there might be spaces mixed with tabs for indentation. Try doing a search & replace to replace all tabs with a few spaces.

Try this:

```
import sys

def Factorial(n): # return factorial
    result = 1
    for i in range (1,n):
        result = result * i
    print "factorial is ",result
    return result

print Factorial(10)
```

Answer (score 330):

***Important***:

Spaces are the ***preferred*** method - see PEP 8 [Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) and [Tabs or Spaces?](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces). (Thanks to @Siha for this.)

For [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) users:

Set Sublime Text to use tabs for indentation:
Menu *View* → *Indentation* → *Convert Indentation to Tabs*

Uncheck the *Indent Using Spaces* option as well in the same sub-menu above.
This will immediately resolve this issue.

Comment: Also whenever using Python, make sure you set a similar option in whichever IDE/Text Editor you use

Comment: Also on ATOM, Packages > Whitespace > Convert Spaces to Tabs and you will avoid a Python's Syntax Error Headache!

Comment: Spaces are the preferred method - see PEP008 [Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) and [Tabs or Spaces?](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces). Sublime can also be setup to do it this way round.

Comment: you say spaces are the preferred method yet your answer asks people to ask sublime to use tabs instead! I am confused

Comment: @NunoCalaim Well unfortunately, that happened after I had answered the question. If you are starting out a new project, please use the preferred technique of spaces. That is why I made an edit in bold so that any newcomers are aware of the disclaimer.

Comment: `cat -T yourfile.py` will help to make this easier to spot. I had a tab at the beginning of a pydoc, and was wondering what removing the pydoc removed this error for me.

Answer (score 152):

To easily check for problems with tabs/spaces you can actually do this:

```
python -m tabnanny yourfile.py
```

or you can just set up your editor correctly of course :-)

Comment: I tried this in a file with some tab/space indentation error, but no output at all with an incorrect tab file. any idea?

Comment: I had a problem with spaces and the error said it was on line 191, but thanks to tabnanny I found the real problem was not on that line, but in the line above.

Comment: Thank you! What a great tip. Error was identified by flake8 in VS Code but it could not identify _where_ the problem was -- tabnanny did in a microsecond.

Answer (score 50):

Are you sure you are not mixing tabs and spaces in your indentation white space? (That will cause that error.)

Note, it is recommended that you don't use tabs in Python code. See the [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You should configure Notepad++ to insert spaces for tabs.

Comment: I'm confused. The answer above states to switch a text editor option to use tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: @BananaCode As long as you use ONLY tabs or ONLY spaces, it technically doesn't matter which you choose. Though for python, spaces are preferred, see the link that I referred to.

Answer (score 29):

Whenever I've encountered this error, it's because I've somehow mixed up tabs and spaces in my editor.

Answer (score 22):

If you are using Vim, hit escape and then type

gg=G

This auto indents everything and will clear up any spaces you have thrown in.

Answer (score 18):

If you use Python's IDLE editor you can do as it suggests in one of similar error messages:

1) select all, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>

2) Go to Format -> Untabify Region

3) Double check your indenting is still correct, save and rerun your program.

I'm using Python 2.5.4

Answer (score 12):

**Using [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)**

If you are using Visual Studio Code, then it will convert all mixed indentation to either space or tabs using these simple steps below.

1. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. type *indent using spaces*
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! Short & sweet! This works for me.

Answer (score 11):

The line: `result = result * i` should be indented (it is the body of the for-loop).

Or - you have mixed space and tab characters

Comment: I had to change the editing in SO, strange. See my updated "Edit" note in the question

Comment: Ok, so I believe that second line of my answer is correct - you have mixed space and tab characters (32 and 8 in ASCII, respectively)

Answer (score 11):

For [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_%28software%29) users, go to

menu *Source* → *Fix Indentation*

to fix the issue immediately.

Answer (score 10):

On [Atom](https://atom.io/)

go to

```
Packages > Whitespace > Convert Spaces to Tabs
```

Then check again your file indentation:

```
python -m tabnanny yourFile.py
```

or

```
>python
>>> help("yourFile.py")
```

Answer (score 9):

If you use [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), do a "replace" with extended search mode to find \t and replace with four spaces.

Answer (score 9):

If you use [Colaboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Industry_adoption), then you can do this to avoid the error by these commands:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd>
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>

It's all [tab] indentation converted to [space] indentation. Then <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Answer (score 8):

Looks to be an indentation problem. You don't have to match curly brackets in Python but you *do* have to match indentation levels.

The best way to prevent space/tab problems is to display invisible characters within your text  editor. This will give you a quick way to prevent and/or resolve indentation-related errors.

Also, injecting copy-pasted code is a common source for this type of problem.

Answer (score 7):

For what it’s worth, my [docstring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring#Python) was indented too much and this also throws the same error

```
class junk:
     """docstring is indented too much"""
    def fun(): return
```

`IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Answer (score 6):

I'm using [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) in the [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) OS. To fix this issue, go to:

Menu *View* → *Indentation* → *Convert indentation to tabs*.

Answer (score 4):

Just a addition. I had a similar problem with the both indentations in Notepad++.

1. Unexcepted indentation
2. Outer Indentation Level

   Go to ----> Search tab ----> tap on **replace** ----> hit the radio button **Extended** below ---> Now replace \t with four spaces

   Go to ----> Search tab ----> tap on **replace** ----> hit the radio button **Extended** below ---> Now replace \n with nothing

Answer (score 4):

I was using [Jupyter Notebook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPython#Project_Jupyter) and tried almost all of the solutions in previous answers (adapting to my scenario) to no use. I then went line by line, deleted all spaces for each line and replaced with tab. That solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It could be because the function above it is not indented the same way.
i.e.

```
class a:
    def blah:
      print("Hello world")
    def blah1:
      print("Hello world")
```

Answer (score 2):

Since I realize there isn't any answer specific to [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_%28software%29), I'll add one:

Basically, carefully look at your `if` statement and make sure all `if`s, `elif`s and `else`s have the same spacing, that is, they're at the same line at the start like so:

```
def your_choice(answer):
    if answer>5:
        print("You're overaged")
    elif answer<=5 and answer>1:
            print("Welcome to the toddler's club!")
    else:
            print("No worries, mate!")
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
1. def convert_distance(miles):
2.   km = miles * 1.6
3.   return km
```

In this code, the same situation occurred for me. Just delete the previous indent spaces of line 2 and 3, and then **either use tab or space. Never use both**. Give proper indentation while writing code in Python.

For [Spyder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spyder_%28software%29), go to menu *Source* → *Fix Indentation*. The same goes for [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) or any other editor. Fix the indentation.

Comment: The *Spyder* part was likely plagiarised from [Abdulbasith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level-although/59602132#59602132).

Answer (score 2):

I am using [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) 3 with a [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) project. I fixed the error using menu *View* → *Indentation* → *Tab Width*: 4 after unselected Indent Using Spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is a mix up of both tabs and spaces.
You can either remove all the spaces and replace them with tabs.

Or, try writing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt
```

at the beginning of the code. This line resolves any differences between tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

For [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)) users, *Packages* → *white space* → *remove trailing white spaces*. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had a function defined, but it *did not have any content* apart from its function comments...

```
def foo(bar):
    # Some awesome temporary comment.
    # But there is actually nothing in the function!
    # D'Oh!
```

It yelled:

```
  File "foobar.py", line 69

                                ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

(note that the line the `^` mark points to is empty)

--

Multiple solutions:

1: Just comment out the function

2: Add function comment

```
def foo(bar):
    '' Some awesome comment. This comment could be just one space.''
```

3: Add a line that does not do anything

```
def foo(bar):
    0
```

In any case, make sure to *make it obvious* **why** it is an empty function - for yourself, or for your peers that will use your code.

Comment: The [pass statement](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/pass.html) could be useful there :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, just to remind you there is a logical error you better keep result=1 or else your output will be result=0 even after the loop runs.

Secondly you can write it like this:

```
import sys

def Factorial(n): # Return factorial
  result = 0
  for i in range (1,n):
     result = result * i

  print "factorial is ",result
  return result
```

Leaving a line will tell the python shell that the FOR statements have ended. If you have experience using the python shell then you can understand why we have to leave a line.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error even though I didn't have any tabs in my code, and the reason was there was a superfluous closing parenthesis somewhere in my code. I should have figured this out earlier, because it was messing up spaces before and after some equal signs...

If you find anything off even after running *Reformat code* in your IDE (or manually running autopep8), make sure all your parentheses match, starting backwards from the weird spaces before/after the first equals sign.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of correcting the indentation error is to copy your
code to PyCharm if you have configured that already and reformat the file
it will automatically indent correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday. It was an indentation error. I was using the [Sublime Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublime_Text) editor.

It took my hours trying to fix it, and at the end I ended up copying the code into the [vi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi) text editor. It just worked fine.

PS: Python is too whitespace sensitive. Make sure not to mix spaces and tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because of another thing, and it was not about tabs vs. spaces. I had the first `if` slightly more indented than an `else:` much further down. If it is just about a space or two; you might oversee it after a long code block. The same thing with docstrings:

```
"""comment comment 
comment
"""
```

They also need to be aligned; see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012979/11154841) on the same page here.

Reproducible with a few lines:

```
if a==1:
    print('test')
 else:
    print('test2')
```

Throws:

```
  File "<ipython-input-127-52bbac35ad7d>", line 3
    else:
         ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar error below:

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

When I forgot to put `pass` to the class or function below, then other code was written after the class or function as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    # pass

x = 10
```

```py
def test():
    # pass

x = 10
```

And, when other code was not written after the class or function as shown below:

```py
class Person:
    # pass

# x = 10
```

```py
def test():
    # pass

# x = 10
```

I got the error below:

> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Answer (score -1):

I actually get this in [Pylint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pylint) from a bracket in the wrong place.

I'm adding this answer, because I sent a lot of time looking for tabs.
In this case, it has nothing to do with tabs or spaces.

```py
    def some_instance_function(self):

        json_response = self.some_other_function()

        def compare_result(json_str, variable):
            """
            Sub function for comparison
            """
            json_value = self.json_response.get(json_str, f"{json_str} not found")

            if str(json_value) != str(variable):
                logging.error("Error message: %s, %s",
                    json_value,
                    variable) # <-- Putting the bracket here causes the error below
                    #) <-- Moving the bracket here fixes the issue
                return False
            return True

        logging.debug("Response: %s", self.json_response)
        #        ^----The pylint error reports here
```

Comment: Convert tabs to spaces. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-notepad

Comment: Anything that PyLint reports is **completely separate from** actual errors from Python. A linter by definition is only there to enforce style, not correctness. Aside from that, this doesn't look reproducible.