# Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level python

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def SaveData():
   
        A=Fresh_strvar.get()
        B=Milk_strvar.get()
        C=Grocery_strvar.get()
        D=Frozen_strvar.get()
        E=Detergents_paper_strvar.get()
        F=Delicatessen_strvar.get()
        print(A)
        print(B)
        print(C)
        print(D)
        print(E)
        print(F)
        
        file1=openpyxl.load_workbook("wholesale.xlsx")
        
        sheet=file1.active
        sheet.cell(column=1,row=sheet.max_row+1,value=A)
        sheet.cell(column=2,row=sheet.max_row,value=B)
        sheet.cell(column=3,row=sheet.max_row,value=C)
        sheet.cell(column=4,row=sheet.max_row,value=D)
        sheet.cell(column=5,row=sheet.max_row,value=E)
        sheet.cell(column=6,row=sheet.max_row,value=F)
        
       file1.save('wholesale..xlsx')
```

Error:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/zipfile.py", line 1247, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'wholesale.xlsx'
.!label6
rayanesgh@rayanes-air ~ % /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/rayanesgh/Desktop/0.py
  File "/Users/rayanesgh/Desktop/0.py", line 37
    file1.save('wholesale..xlsx')
                                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: Last line has one space too little. Add one before file.save and you'll be good to go.

Comment: You have a couple errors here. "No such file or directory: 'wholesale.xlsx'" and the indentation error. I would fix your code indentation. That may resolve the file error as well. If you are using an IDE, most offer an auto formatting option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: "Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711756/python-indentation-error-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level) Specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58774681/16775594

Comment: As @CaptainCaveman mentioned using an IDE like [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) can really make format issues so much easier to learn and follow.

Answer (score 0):

The last line isn't indented like the other lines:

```
def SaveData():
   
        A=Fresh_strvar.get()
        B=Milk_strvar.get()
        C=Grocery_strvar.get()
        D=Frozen_strvar.get()
        E=Detergents_paper_strvar.get()
        F=Delicatessen_strvar.get()
        print(A)
        print(B)
        print(C)
        print(D)
        print(E)
        print(F)
        
        file1=openpyxl.load_workbook("wholesale.xlsx")
        
        sheet=file1.active
        sheet.cell(column=1,row=sheet.max_row+1,value=A)
        sheet.cell(column=2,row=sheet.max_row,value=B)
        sheet.cell(column=3,row=sheet.max_row,value=C)
        sheet.cell(column=4,row=sheet.max_row,value=D)
        sheet.cell(column=5,row=sheet.max_row,value=E)
        sheet.cell(column=6,row=sheet.max_row,value=F)
        
       file1.save('wholesale..xlsx')
       ^
```

Should be something like this:

```
        sheet.cell(column=4,row=sheet.max_row,value=D)
        sheet.cell(column=5,row=sheet.max_row,value=E)
        sheet.cell(column=6,row=sheet.max_row,value=F)
        
        file1.save('wholesale..xlsx')
```