# In Python the difference between += and =

Tags: python, operators

for example

```
A+=A=a
```

output:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

in the same time with `B+=B+b` is working fine!

so whats the difference between `=` and `+=` with Python

Comment: The exception has **nothing** to do with `+=` versus `=`.

Comment: What do you expect the first example to do?

Comment: x += 1 means the same as x = x + 1. so B+=B+b means the same as B=B+B+b. The problem with the first example (A+=A=a) is the second "=" between A and a. this has nothing to do with the +=

Comment: Running this code in `C++` gives http://ideone.com/NI1w9r Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A += 1` means `A = A + 1`. So `A += A = a` would be `A = A + A = a` (which obviously doesnt work).

The error you seem to experience is not caused by this operator. Perhaps you mixed spaces with tabs, or you simply did not indent a certain line when it should have been.

Comment: Thanks, i mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: @user2462574 Common mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

`A = a` It's a simple assignment,
while
`A += a` Is equivalent to

```
A = A + a
```

This occurs in most programming languages

Answer (score 0):

a `+=` a would be read

```
a is a plus a
```

Therefore, `A += A` is

```
A is A plus A
```

`A += A` is short for `A = A + A`

The [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level) has nothing to do with your operator layout.

Answer (score 0):

1. what do you mean to do with `A+=A=a`? Make sure your purpose before you do anything.
2. try to do your job step by step, instead of get the whole piece at once.
3. `a += 1` equals `a = a + 1`, that's the meaning and usage of `+=`.