# unindent does not match any outer indentation level [duplicate_same]

Tags: python

When i make error?
Don't see errors. Please, help me.

```
datafile = file('c:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test.txt')
    for line in datafile:
        if '5256' in line:
            GLOBACCESS[jid]=100
            reply('private', source, u'You license is valid!')
        else:   
            reply('private', source, u'Incorrect password/jid')
```

Comment: you're mixing tabs and spaces.

Comment: Why is your `for line in datafile:` line indented?

Comment: Mixing tabs and spaces won't trigger an error in Python 2.x, but it's bad programming practice regardless. Your error lies in the indentation of the for loop.

Comment: Hint: If you're getting a message saying your question has a duplicate title, you might want to take a look at the question it links to. If you look at the sidebar, you'll notice multiple similar questions that you can look at. For example, [this highly rated one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level?rq=1).

Comment: @jmu303: that is incorrect. Mixing tabs and spaces does raise errors in python2.x... depending on how you mix them

Comment: @inspectorG4dget really? I'm sure you know more than me, I'm just inferring from [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)

Comment: @jmu303: I've gotten those errors before

Comment: @inspectorG4dget "When invoking the Python 2 command line interpreter with the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs and spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options are highly recommended!"

My assumption was that if these options weren't chosen, Python wouldn't throw errors?

Comment: Python2 interprets tabs as 8 spaces without complaint as long as that works indentation-wise

Comment: @jmu303: Fair point. That makes sense

Comment: BTW, according to the documentation you shouldn't use `file` to open a file. Use `open` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Lines 2 and 3 are using spaces while everything else is using tabs. You always need to use the same, and should choose spaces per [pep 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Line 2 shouldn't be indented at all, with spaces *or* with tabs

Comment: how are you able to tell the difference between spaces and tabs in OP's post?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget hit edit on the OP's post and look at the raw copy/pasted text.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget, click edit to select the original code. Then cancel

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop shouldn't be indented.

```
datafile = file('c:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\test.txt')
for line in datafile:
     if '5256' in line:
        GLOBACCESS[jid]=100
        reply('private', source, u'You license is valid!')
     else:   
        reply('private', source, u'Incorrect password/jid')
```