# Distance of Robot from Starting Point after a Series of Movements

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7

I am trying to write a program which takes a list of directions and magnitudes and outputs the distance of the robot from its starting position.

I get an error when executing the following code but I cannot identify why I get the error.

```
import math

position = [0,0]
direction = ['+Y','-X','-Y','+X','-X','-Y','+X']
magnitude = [9,7,4,8,3,6,2]
i = 0

while i < len(direction):
    if direction[i] == '+Y': position[0] += magnitude[i]
    elif direction[i] == '-Y': position[0] -= magnitude[i]
    elif direction[i] == '+X': position[1] += magnitude[i]
    elif direction[i] == '-X': position[1] -= magnitude[i]
    else: pass
    i += 1

print float(math.sqrt(position[1]**2+position[0]**2))
```

Edit:

I get this error:

`IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Comment: please post the error aswell

Comment: I just ran this and got no error

Comment: @user2357 You will probably get correct distance. But the position will be a bit wrong, as on lines with `+X` and `-X` you swapped `-=` and `+=`.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that mistake, I should have used up, down, etc. +x, -x etc. is a bit confusing. I don't get any distance at all though.

Comment: @user2357 you probably mixed tabs and spaces. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level

Comment: You're mixing tabs and spaces. You use spaces to begin with, but switch to tabs for the `if` part. Use spaces throughout.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that I could get an error from mixing tabs and spaces. Good to know.

Comment: Fixed. I get an answer now! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you have mixed up your spaces and tabs. In this instance, it might be easier to put the sign within the magnitude and filter with `x` and `y` like so:

```
In [15]: mDr = [ (int(d[0]+m), d[1]) for (d, m) in zip(direction, map(str, magnitude))]

In [16]: mDr
Out[16]: [(9, 'Y'), (-7, 'X'), (-4, 'Y'), (8, 'X'), (-3, 'X'), (-6, 'Y'), (2, 'X')]
```

In this case, you can get to total x and y distances pretty easily. For example, the y distances:

```
In [17]: [md[0]  for md in mDr if md[1] =='Y']
Out[17]: [9, -4, -6]
```

And the total `y` distance in the particular direction:

```
In [18]: sum( [md[0]  for md in mDr if md[1] =='Y'] )
Out[18]: -1
```

You can do the same for `x` and then calculate the distance that way.

Answer (score -1):

Here comes my offtopic reaction (your problem was mixing tabs and spaces, my answer is simple rewrite).

```
import math

xymoves = {"+X": (1, 0), "-X": (-1, 0), "+Y": (0, 1), "-Y": (0, -1)}

position = [0, 0]
directions = ['+Y', '-X', '-Y', '+X', '-X', '-Y', '+X']
assert all(xymove in xymoves for xymove in directions)
magnitudes = [9, 7, 4, 8, 3, 6, 2]

for direction, magnitude in zip(directions, magnitudes):
    xmove, ymove = xymoves[direction]
    position[0] += magnitude * xmove
    position[1] += magnitude * ymove

print math.sqrt(position[1]**2+position[0]**2)
```

Changes:

- looping using `for` and not `while` with incrementing index.
- the logic "where to move" moved from `if elif elif` into dictionary `xymoves`
- rejecting to process direction, which is not expected
- `math.sqrt` always returns `float`, so conversion to `float` removed

Note, that the dictionary with xymoves could be extended with other directions, e.g. using "N" for North, "NE" for North-East etc.

Comment: I don't get it. Why shouldn't I upvote this? Is it not an answer?

Comment: @EmilVikström Of course you can upvote it. I just wanted to highlight, that my answer is not reacting to real problem from the question.