# Populate wxChoice at Start of Program Run | Python

Tags: python, populate, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

As soon as my program is run, I want my wxChoice to be populated with items from a list I designate. I am using wxFormBuilder to handle the GUI elements of my program.

My code:

```
    def onDropDownSelection(self, parent):

    #Open designated file 
    lines = tuple(open("/Users/it/Desktop/Classbook/masterClassList.txt", 'r'))

    #Strips the first line of the file, splits the elements, assigns to "one"
    lines[1].rstrip()
    one = lines[1].split("|")

    #My attempt to populate the wxChoice with my list "one"
    self.firstChoice.SetItems(one)
```

This event is activated when the user clicks on the drop-down (wxChoice) menu, and re-populates every time it is clicked on.

Is there a way I can populate my wxChoice, only once, upon the initial opening/running of the program?

I have placed this code where the wxChoice is being created. However, I am now experiencing a "Unindent does not match any outer indentation level" on line 44. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I'm familiar with PyQt, but why do you populate the drop-down menu every time the user clicks it?
Is the content of the drop-down menu dynamically created or is it always the same?

Because if the content of the drop-down menu stays the same, you could populate the wxChoice while creating it.

Comment: @ProgrammingIsAwsome would my code be the same, rather I just place it where the wxChoice is being created?

Comment: Yes this would be it. Create the wxChoice and then populate it.

Comment: @ProgrammingIsAwsome Please see my edit above. I have placed the code where I am creating the wxChoice but am experiencing an "Indent" error on line 44.

Comment: I've posted an answer with a link to it. Hope things are clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for your indentation. Some times if you copy paste, this can mess things up.
Just rewrite it or replace it with another statement. See here:
[IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Problem is if you make your indentation with tabs and then copy-paste some code from an example page, where the indentation is made with spaces. Then you have mixed Indentations. I've had these a lot of times.