# SpeechRecognition as a function

Tags: python, function, speech-recognition

So i'm working in python with SpeechRecognition : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/
It works perfectly with this code:

```
import pyaudio
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer(language = "es-ES", key = "AIzaSyBOti4mM-6x9WDnZIjIeyEU21OpBXqWBgw")
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
print r.recognize(audio)
```

But when I try to turn it into a function:

```
def stt():
    r = sr.Recognizer(language = "es-ES", key = "AIzaSyBOti4mM-6x9WDnZIjIeyEU21OpBXqWBgw")
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
    return r.recognize(audio)
```

I get this error: `File "./prueba_2.py", line 22
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
                                  ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

How could i fix it?

Comment: Fix indentation in your script. In Python it is important. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level

Comment: If ``key`` variable is an API key of some kind, for some external servise, it might be wise to generate new keys, and delete these, I think you shouldn't have posted them.