# error in python idfs implementation

Tags: python

I am new in python, there is this error in the if else statement `"unindent does not match any outer indentation level"`, can anyone tell me what is the problem with if else statements?

```
def idfs(graph, start, end,limit):
    # maintain a queue of paths
    count=0
    queue = []

    # push the first path into the queue
    queue.append([start])
    #print queue

    while queue:
        count +=1
        # get the first path from the queue
        path = queue.pop(0)

        # get the last node from the path
        node = path[-1]

        # path found
        if node == end and count==2:
            return path
        elif node!=end and count==2:
            print 'goal not found'
            limit=input('Enter the limit again')
         path=idfs(graph,node,goal,limit)
         return path




        # enumerate all adjacent nodes, construct a new path and push it into the queue
        for adjacent in graph.get(node, []):
            new_path = list(path)
            print new_path
            new_path.append(adjacent)
            print new_path
            queue.append(new_path)
            print queue


# example execution of code
start = input('Enter source node: ')
goal = input('Enter goal node: ')
limit=input('Enter the limit')

print(idfs(graph,start,goal,limit))
```

Comment: Apart from solving indentation You should replace elif with else in this case

Comment: possible duplicate of [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Answer (score 1):

The two lines after `elif` are misaligned. Depending on whether they belong to `while` or inside `elif`, move them either 1 space to the left or 3 spaces to the right to solve the issue.