# Can someone figure out why i'm getting error's

Tags: python

I am new to python and i'm following this tutorial but im getting this error.
There's an error in your program:

```
unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

This is the code.

```
def Xero():
    print 'Here is some content!'
    print 'And some more...!'
    for i in xrange(5):
        print 'Hello!'
Xero()
```

Comment: Okay I've indented it. Does it work as it should now?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Perhaps in your actual file you've mixed tabs and spaces?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level?rq=1

Comment: definitely sounds like you are indenting wrong.  don't use both tabs and spaces.

Comment: Thanks guys it works now i don't know why it didnt work but i appreciate all you're help!

Comment: Use a good IDE like PyCharm to edit Python code. That way you won't have this kind of error.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you have mixed tabs and spaces in your code. Use only spaces or tabs, but don't mix between the two.

The recommendation is to use spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error when dealing with spaces. You probably have an extra space before `Xero()`, or some of your print statements have mixed tabs/spaces before them. I generally find that in order to get the spacing right, I copy all of the whitespace from before the first argument, and paste it on all the lines after. It might help to use an IDE such as spyder to avoid problems like this.

P.S. - Since you're new to python, you should try Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for Python style. PEP 8 says: Indentation

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.
>
> For really old code that you don't want to mess up, you can continue
>   to use 8-space tabs

**Tabs or Spaces?**

> Never mix tabs and spaces.
>
> The most popular way of indenting Python is with spaces only. The
>   second-most popular way is with tabs only. Code indented with a
>   mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces
>   exclusively. When invoking the Python command line interpreter with
>   the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs
>   and spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options
>   are highly recommended!