# Getting error while executing

Tags: python

```
class Employee:

def displayEmployee(self):

   a=120

   print a

emp1 = Employee()

print (emp1.displayEmployee())
```

i am also getting 
120
None

i want to remove none from my output

Comment: Your indentation got messed up pasting into the question, but I bet the problem is here ` print a`. Note there is an extra space. Python is picky about indentation. All you need to do is remove the space.

Comment: What's unclear about that error message?  It even tells you which line to look at.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Comment: Thank you so much Rooney I stuck two days for it.

Comment: @ateek ask a new question rather than progressively adding new questions to the same post. That's one thing that don't half piss off answerers. The simple answer though is to remove the second print. Your function has no return statement and so returns `None`. That is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not formatted, but the error tells you that you have a wrong indentation. Your code should be:

```
class Employee:
    def displayEmployee(self):
        a=120
        print a

emp1 = Employee()
print (emp1.displayEmployee())
```

This will get you rid of the `IndentationError`, and presumably do what you want. However, the last line should be:

```
emp1.displayEmployee()
```

instead of `print(...)`, because the `displayEmployee` method prints itself something, and does not return anything to print.

Comment: Thank you so much leg I stuck two days for it.

Comment: @Ateek My pleasure. Be careful with Python's indentation, it might get you errors even after years of practice.