# Sudden IndentationError from copy-pasted code

Tags: python, loops, indentation

**Set-up**

I scrape housing ads per city, using Scrapy.
Per city I create a spider, which I adjust (a little) per city when needed.

---

**Problem**

I copy-pasted my code from City A in a `.py` file, intended to scrape City B. I've done this many times before. Now however I receive an `IndentationError` for the following lines in the code,

```
pl=[]
for key, value in df['postal'].iteritems():
    temp = value
    pl.append(str(temp))
```

The error is for `temp` and states `IndentationError: expected an indented block`. 
There is no indentation error if I run the code for city A. However, the copy-pasted code for B gives this error.

Moreover, if I enter or remove an extra white space, the lines run fine but then I receive an `IndentationError` at the next loop – enter/remove an extra white space at that loop will allow me to continue to the subsequent loop whereupon I receive the same error, etc.

I've also run `python -m tabnanny yourfile.py` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513524/7326714), but to no effect: `Clean bill of health.`

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. This was a silly thing.

I copy pasted the entire file, but not correctly. That is, at the top of the file where I state which modules to input there was an unnecessary indent. I.e.

```
     import pandas as pd
```

instead of,

```
import pandas as pd
```

This resulted in the indentation error at any loop.

---

Answer (score 0):

Left align all the copy pasted code and again give the proper indentation with tabs. copy pasted code sometimes takes wrong indentation.