# Python dictionary to dataframe - DataFrame constructor not properly called

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I used a dictionary containing `source-destination` as keys and `messages` as values. It loops over the first dataframe, for each question, store who posted 1st message as the destination, store who posted 2nd message as source, add a counter in dictionary at key 'source-destination'.

Now I am trying to convert dictionary to dataframe, but I get this error message

`ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import permutations

df = pd.read_csv('example.csv', sep=';', engine='python')

messages = {}  # the dictionary where results is going to be stored
student= set()
destination = False  # a simple boolean to make sure message 2 follows message 1

for row in df:  # iterate over the dataframe
    student.add(row[2])  # collect students' name
    if row[1] == 1:  # if it is an initial message
        destination = row[2]  # we store students as destination
    elif row[1] == 2 and destination:  # if this is a second message
        source = row[2]  # store student as source
        key = source + "-" + destination  # construct a key based on source/destination
        if key not in messages:  # if the key is new to dictionary
            messages[key] = 1  # create the new entry
        else:  # otherwise
            messages[key] += 1  # add a counter to the existing entry
        destination = False  # reset destination

    else:
        destination = False  # reset destination

# add the pairs of source-destination who didn't interact in the dictionnary
for pair in permutations(student, 2):
    if "-".join(pair) not in messages:
        messages["-".join(pair)] = 0

 f1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(messages)
 print(f1)
```

Any idea why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Comment: It looks like your python code is wrongly indented. Maybe the space before `f1` at the end? Nothing to do with pandas anyway.

Comment: @lanS Thanks!You're right! Now I got another error message: pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! Any hint?

Comment: Hi @Giada, shall we go back [on chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143803/discussion-between-giada-and-trolldejo) ?

Comment: My guess would be you need to `from_dict` now.

Comment: @lanS check another error type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have a mix between tab and space in your code.
Try to remove all the tabs and replace them with spaces.

Same problem : [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Comment: Thank you! the problem is fixed but now I got another one pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called! Any suggestion? @Sushii