# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level model.py line 36

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new in python as well as Django. i got error (IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level)
 line 36 model.py

below is my code
[image]

```
class Load_ProviderRegistration(models.Model):
    def number(): // i got error in this line 
        no = Load_ProviderRegistration.objects.count()
        if no == None:
            return 1
        else:
            return no + 1
    Load_Provider_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True,default=number)
    Load_Provider_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=13)
```

Comment: FYI, comments in Python use `#`

Comment: Also, you `number()` should be `number(self)` if within a class..

Comment: Why would you think pasting your code in the comments section would help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few things to note here:

1. Mixing tabs and spaces is not allowed in python. Using 4 spaces as an indention level is adviced by [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation) or read this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level?rq=1).
2. Passing the `self` as the methods first argument if the method is not `static`.

   `def number(self):
       ...`

extra:

3. Comments are marked by a hashtag ( `#` ).
4. `x == None` comparement can be written as `if x is None`.
   In your case `if no == None` would be `if no is None`.