# IPython magic %paste: unindent error with large block of code

Tags: python, terminal, ipython

When pasting in a large class (>800 lines), it seems like IPython can lose track of the indentations and then will return an IndentationError:

```
In [1]: %paste
  File "<tokenize>", line 772
    (self.D['Department']==dept) &
    ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Might be a memory or terminal overflow issue, but wanted to post here for reference since one can spend hours trying to track down tabs that don't exist and turn them into spaces. When you google or SO for IndentationError, "replace tabs with spaces" is [literally the only solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level). This obviously won't work in this case.

This is not a duplicate, it's a similar *error* but a very different *issue*.

Comment: Without a clear [mre] and/or specific finding of what triggers the problem or what to do about it, along with a clear statement of a *question* rather than what sounds like a bug report, there is not a useful Q&A here. At best, this material could provide comments on an answer at the now-marked duplicate, or perhaps a reason to edit an answer there.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've come up with is to call the code block from the command line. The IPython compiler seems to have no issue, the problem is probably with the magic %paste buffer.

`$ ipython code_block.py`