# Problems with "else:"?

Tags: python

I am very new in python. Could you help?

```
x = 1 
y = 0


if x > y: 
   if x < 0:
         print (" X é maior que Y e menor que 0.")
    else:
         print (" X é maior que Y e maior que 0.")

if x < y:
      if x < 0:
            print ("X é menor que Y e menor que 0.")
       else:
            print ("X é menor que Y e maior que 0.")
```

line 16
    else:
        ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
[Finished in 0.1s]

That is the error? Why?

Thank for your help, 
Ricardo Rocha

Comment: In both cases you can see with the naked eye that it is not indented to the same level as the preceding `if`

Comment: Your `else` statements are not indented in the same way as your `if` statements.  If you squint you can see it.

Comment: `if` and `else` need to have *exactly* the same indentation level.

Comment: Your `if` and `else` need to be vertically aligned ... the `else` is out by one character

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Answer (score 2):

Your indentations are wrong. Python uses whitespace as part of the code formatting. `if` and `else` need to have the same indentation level.

```
x = 1 
y = 0


if x > y: 
    if x < 0:
        print (" X é maior que Y e menor que 0.")
    else:
        print (" X é maior que Y e maior que 0.")

if x < y:
    if x < 0:
        print ("X é menor que Y e menor que 0.")
    else:
        print ("X é menor que Y e maior que 0.")
```

Comment: This is a typo, man.  Should be closed as such.

Comment: I agree, but I'm not sure why this answer was downvoted. Typo or not, he's right.

Comment: @emsimpson92:  That's neither here nor there.  The question should be closed instead of answered, since it's not going to be of lasting value to anyone looking for this answer (since there's ***already*** a wealth of information about this in Python).

Comment: I didn't upvote or downvote the answer either way. I just flagged it as a duplicate, but if someone wants to answer a duplicate I guess I just don't see an issue with that.