# python 3.7 while true loop gives error about unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, while-loop

```
user = "admin"
password = "admin"
while true:
    ques1 = input("Enter your username: ")
    ques2 = input("Enter your password:")
 if ques1 == user and ques2 == password :
     print("Welcome")
     break
 else :
     print("username or password are wrong ! \nplease try again !")
```

python 3.7 while true loop gives error about unindent does not match any outer indentation level error on line 3

Comment: You have spaces before the `if` and `else` statements which shouldn't be there. Voting to close as just a typo.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Comment: Or maybe the extra spaces whereby `ques1` and `ques2` assignments are indented further than the `if`s are the ones that are wrong (and those two lines should only have a single space at the front, the same way the `if` and `else` do); it's a question of authorial intent. (That said, best practice is to follow PEP-8 and only use 4-space indents, without a compelling reason to do otherwise).

Comment: still give me same error , i delete the line 3 (while true:) and code is working ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indent is bad, are you using an IDE ?? Your code should look like the below, also it's while True, not true.

```py
user = "admin"
password = "admin"
while True:
    ques1 = input("Enter your username: ")
    ques2 = input("Enter your password:")
    if ques1 == user and ques2 == password :
        print("Welcome")
        break
    else :
        print("username or password are wrong ! \nplease try again !")
```

Comment: thanks for the help! now code is working , I'm using the visual studio code and i trun off the auto fix,  that's where I'm wrong

Comment: Try to use the auto-correction, or go for something more user friendly as pyCharm. The correction helps you learn and memorize the structure of the language syntax more.