# Repeatedly ask a user for a value until conditions are met

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that returns True if integer n is positive and odd (otherwise False). Then  use this function to repeatedly ask a user to enter a positive and odd integer until a (positive and odd) integer has been provided up to five times and return the value once it fulfils the positive/odd criteria.

I can get it to return if it's true or false but I'm getting stuck on the rest.

Here's what I've tried:

```
x = int(input("enter a number: "))
values = [5]
def isOdd(x):

    if x % 2 != 0 and x>0:

           return True
        print("yup")
     else:
           return False
        print("no")


'''while count = <5 and x % 2 != 0 and x>0: #this is a different approach I tried
    count = sum x+1
    print ("no")
    x = int(input("enter a number: "))'''

    
for i in range(x):
    values.append(int(input('Please enter a value')))
```

What am I missing here? I'm new to programming and having a little bit of trouble figuring out functions and append.

Changed code to:

```
x = int(input("enter a number: "))
def isOdd(x):

    if x % 2 != 0 and x>0:

           return True
        print("yup")
     else:
           return False
        print("no")


while count <=5 and not isOdd(x):
    count = sum x+1
    print ("no")
    x = int(input("enter a number: "))
```

Getting this error now:

```
line 12
    print("yup")
               ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

Comment: *until a proper (positive and odd) integer has been provided* What is a proper number?

Comment: Oh I'll remove that, never mind the word proper.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Comment: Your indentation problem is an unrelated issue.  You have to post this as a separate SO question ... except that it's a simply typo: fix your indentation.  If you're confused, look up Python indentation requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close.  You just need to call your function with the input value, and the use the result:

```
# Stay in this loop until 5 wrong guesses, or one right guess.
while count <=5 and not isOdd(x):
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the code to include your answer. 
it's giving me the error:
`
     print("yup")
               ^
    IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
`
When my code is:
`
x = int(input("enter a number: "))
def isOdd(x):

    if x % 2 != 0 and x>0:

           return True
        print("yup")
     else:
           return False
        print("no")

while count <=5 and not isOdd(x):
    count = sum x+1
    print ("no")
    x = int(input("enter a number: "))
`

Comment: (1) A follow-up question goes into a new posting.  (2) Your original posted code contains this error; it's not due to what I suggested.  (3) As you can see, a comment is a nearly useless way to post code.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question and added the current code and error. I'm new to Stackoverflow and appreciate your help :)