# Expected an indented block in tensorflow kera

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting an error like this:

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

```
def pure_cnn_model():

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
featurewise_center=False,
samplewise_center=False,
featurewise_std_normalization=False,
samplewise_std_normalization=False,
zca_whitening=False,
rotation_range=45,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True,
vertical_flip=False)

datagen.fit(x_train)
```

Comment: add tab before every line after the first one xd

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Comment: yes it does ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def pure_cnn_model():

    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,
        samplewise_center=False,
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,
        zca_whitening=False,
        rotation_range=45,
        width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=False)

datagen.fit(x_train)
```

Comment: nice answer, totally deserves points xd

Comment: copy paste and Ctrl-K-F is faster than typing a detailed enough comment

Comment: and I doubt I get any points :)

Comment: jk its cool, still a funny question

Comment: yep can you answer 1 more question @Marcin

Comment: if ur there online

Comment: augmented_model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                        optimizer='adam',
                        metrics=['accuracy'])

Comment: im getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'compile'

Comment: @Andrey can also answer

Comment: please please .

Comment: check value of augmented_model

Comment: its not printing anything

Comment: @Andrey where to check?

Comment: I think it equals to None. So you can not compile it

Comment: how do i rectify it?

Comment: @Andrey do you know

Comment: You have to create your model before compiling

Comment: @Andrey only building the model is fine?

Comment: you need to create model. Not build