# IndentationError:at second char.lower()?

Tags: python

Ok , so for some days i continously get this error and i make simple python problems and this still comes out of nowhere i really dont understand what i m wrong with

```
def counterpartCharCode(char):
    a = char.upper()
    b = char.lower()
    if char == a:
        return ord(b)
    else:
        return ord(a)

print(counterpartCharCode("A"))
```

File "e:/salut.py", line 3
b = char.lower()
^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: copied your code and work fine... could your indentation issue only in your IDE?

Comment: can you give us a screenshot?

Comment: Get a better IDE/text editor. One that shows whitespace characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed tabs and spaces, a mortal sin. Editing your code I see

```
SSSTa = char.upper()
SSSSb = char.lower()
```

where S is space and T is tab.