# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level I don't see the issue

Tags: python, indentation

Keep getting this error:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

It is pointing at the end of this line:

```
relevantfolder = drive + ':\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\CADIQ_v' + version + '_si'
```

My code:

```
if test == criteria[2]:
   pass
   relevantfolder = drive + ':\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\CADIQ_v' + version + '_si'
      testsuccess = 0
      for file in os.listdir(relevantfolder):
         if file.startswith('CADIQ'):
            testsuccess = 1
            content += relevantfolder + os.sep + file + '\n'
      if not testsuccess:
         content += 'DID NOT FIND SHORTCUT ' + relevantfolder + '\n'
```

Comment: As posted, the `pass` line and the `relevantfolder = ...` line are at exactly the same indentation level, so it's not clear what the problem is.  Is the posted code accurate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Comment: @Zoe The situation here is different from the post you linked.

Answer (score 0):

From

```
if test == criteria[2]:
   pass
   relevantfolder = drive + ':\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\CADIQ_v' + version + '_si'
      testsuccess = 0
      for file in os.listdir(relevantfolder):
         if file.startswith('CADIQ'):
            testsuccess = 1
            content += relevantfolder + os.sep + file + '\n'
      if not testsuccess:
         content += 'DID NOT FIND SHORTCUT ' + relevantfolder + '\n'
```

to

```
if test == criteria[2]:
    pass
relevantfolder = f'{drive}:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\CADIQ_v{version}_si'
testsuccess = 0
for file in os.listdir(relevantfolder):
    if file.startswith('CADIQ'):
        testsuccess = 1
        content += relevantfolder + os.sep + file + '\n'
if not testsuccess:
    content += 'DID NOT FIND SHORTCUT ' + relevantfolder + '\n'
```

Note that the `pass` doesn't do anything to the code.