# SQLite3 and Python: Why doesn't my table print?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite

Okay so here's what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to build a database with three tables. Bookings, Trainers, and Trainings. So far, I've tried looking online, watching a ton of YouTube videos, but I my code doesn't seem to run. Also, How do I query for

1. all the bookings of a specific trainer
2. find the gender of the trainer for a type of training.
   [image: ERD diagram for the tables]

Heres my current code:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
import os

# Create a connection to the SQLite database via DB file.
def create_connection(db_file):
    """create a database connection to the SQLite database
    specified by db_file
    :param db_file:database file
    :return:Connection object or None
    """
    
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)
    return conn


# Create tables from SQL statement
def create_table(conn,create_table_sql):
    """
    :param conn:Connection object
    :param create_table_sql:a CREATE TABLE statement
    :return:
    """

    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(create_table_sql)
    except Error as e:
        print(e)    
    
# Function to print Bookings Table
def print_table_bookings(conn, bookings):
    sql=""" INSERT INTO bookings VALUES (booking_id,trainer_id,training_id,session_date,session_slot)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"""
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(sql,bookings)
    conn.commit()
    return c.lastrowid

# Function to print Trainers Table
def print_table_trainers(conn, trainers):
    sql=""" INSERT INTO trainers VALUES (trainer_id,name,gender,mobile,specialisation,rate)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"""
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute(sql,trainers)
    conn.commit()
    return c.lastrowid

# Function to print Trainings Table
def print_table_trainings(conn, trainings):
    sql=""" INSERT INTO trainings VALUES (training_id,description,duration)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"""
    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute(sql,trainings)
    conn.commit()
    return c.lastrowid

# Print tables
# Print Bookings
def display_bookings(conn):
    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM bookings")
    rows=c.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
        print("\n") 
        
# Print Bookings
def display_trainers(conn):
    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM trainers")
    rows=c.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
        print("\n")
        
# Print Bookings
def display_trainings(conn):
    c=conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM trainings")
    rows=c.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
        print("\n")
        
# Query to display Trainer's bookings by Trainer's Name
# NOT DONE

# Main Code
def main():
    database = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "\healthhub.db"

    # Create Bookings Table
    sql_create_bookings_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bookings (
                                booking_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                trainer_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                training_id TEXT,
                                session_date INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                session_slot TEXT NOT NULL,
                                FOREIGN KEY(trainer_id) REFERENCES trainer(id),
                                FOREIGN KEY(training_id) REFERENCES training(id)
                                );"""

    # Create Trainer Table
    sql_create_trainers_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trainers (
                                trainer_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                name TEXT NOT NULL,
                                gender TEXT NOT NULL,
                                mobile TEXT NOT NULL,
                                specialisation TEXT NOT NULL,
                                rate INTEGER NOT NULL
                                );"""

    # Create Trainings Table
    sql_create_trainings_table = """ CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trainings (
                                training_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                description TEXT NOT NULL,
                                duration INTEGER NOT NULL
                                );"""

    # Create a Database(DB) Connection
    conn = create_connection(database)

    # Create Tables using def above
    if conn is not None: 
        create_table(conn,sql_create_bookings_table)
        create_table(conn,sql_create_trainers_table)
        create_table(conn,sql_create_trainings_table)

        with conn:
            # Error prevention
            c=conn.cursor()
            c.execute("DELETE FROM bookings;");
            c.execute("DELETE FROM trainers;");
            c.execute("DELETE FROM trainings;");

            # Populating the tables
            many_bookings = [
                                ('0010','001','0001','01082021','Morning'),
                                ('0011','002','0001','01082021','Morning'),
                                ('0012','002','0001','01082021','Morning'),
                                ('0013','002','0001','01082021','Morning'),
                                ('0014','002','0001','01082021','Morning'),
                                ('0015','003','0001','01082021','Morning'),
                                ('0016','004','0001','01082021','Morning'),
                                ('0017','003','0001','01082021','Morning'),
                                ('0018','004','0001','01082021','Morning'),
                                ('0019','004','0001','01082021','Morning')
                            ]
            c.executemany ("INSERT INTO bookings VALUES (?,?,?,?,?", many_bookings)

            many_trainers = [
                                ('001','Gary','Male','91234567','Weight Loss','85'),
                                ('002','Bary','Male','91234568','Weight Loss','185'),
                                ('003','Mary','Female','91234569','Weight Loss','85'),
                                ('004','Stephanie','Female','91234570','Weight Loss','85'),
                                ('005','Austin','Male','91234571','Weight Loss','65'),
                                ('006','Tynia','Female','91234572','Weight Loss','85'),
                                ('007','Oswald','Male','91234573','Weight Loss','55'),
                                ('008','Aria','Fenale','91234574','Weight Loss','45'),
                                ('009','Micheal','Male','91234575','Weight Loss','95'),
                                ('010','Lily','Female','91234576','Weight Loss','105'),
                                ('011','Janet','Female','91234577','Weight Loss','99'),
                                ('012','Imane','Female','91234578','Weight Loss','68'),
                            ]
            c.executemany("INSERT INTO bookings VALUES (?,?,?,?,?", many_trainers)

            many_trainings = [
                                ('0001','Weight Loss','90'),
                                ('0001','Weight Loss','90'),
                                ('0001','Weight Loss','90'),
                                ('0001','Weight Loss','90'),
                                ('0001','Weight Loss','90'),
                                ('0001','Weight Loss','90'),
                                ('0001','Weight Loss','90'),
                                ('0001','Weight Loss','90'),
                                ('0001','Weight Loss','90'),
                                ('0001','Weight Loss','90'),
                            ]
            c.executemany("INSERT INTO bookings VALUES (?,?,?,?,?", many_trainings)

            #Displaying Table
            print_table_bookings(conn)
            print()
            print_table_trainers()
            print()
            print_table_trainings()
            print()
                
            
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

If there's a more efficient way of adding data to the tables, please I would love to get some feedback. I'm really new to coding but I've spent my entire weekend trying to fix it.

The error I get is on line 55

> File "C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\Sem 9\CSE115\Assignment 2\Actual\A2
> (Version 4).py", line 155, in main
> c.executemany ("INSERT INTO bookings VALUES (?,?,?,?,?", many_bookings)
>
> OperationalError: incomplete input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492387/indentationerror-unindent-does-not-match-any-outer-indentation-level)

Comment: @NguyenThaiBinh nope. I think I messed up the creation of tables somehow. But your second comment helps.

Comment: The error is not telling me that. Have you checked for any '\t\ characters in your code?

Comment: I read the post and did the fix (using Sublime text). It got fixed, but it's still not running correctly. The table is still not printing.

Comment: In that case, can you edit your question to show the error you are facing?

Comment: There are a lot of copy & paste mistakes in your code. Try to go through it yourself first before posting.