# Python indentation on notepad++

Tags: python, indentation

Every time I write a function in notepad++ it won't indent for me even when I'm pretty sure I have auto-indent selected. I then manually do 4 spaces and do two print commands but it's not working. It says `'unexpected indent'` in Powershell. Here's what I'm using:

```
def print_twice():
    print "hi"
    print "hi"

print_twice()
```

Comment: Your first `print` line is spaces, your second is tabs

Comment: Sorry, that was just an error on here I think.

Comment: Does it tell you what line the `unexpected_indent` exception occurs?

Comment: Yeah, it's on line 3.

Comment: Oh. I just did some backspacing on the print statements and reset them and it worked. It's a weird method though.

Comment: Settings->Preferences->Tab settings: put 4 in spaces and check Replace by spaces.

Comment: It's weird through because for the first print line it doesn't indent it and I have all those settings on but the second print line indents.

Comment: The first print line I have to space manually for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your notepad++ to always convert tabs to whitespace, or to show whitespace characters. Please see answers [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366499/notepad-indentation-messes-up)

Comment: It's already set to white space but it keeps ignoring the first print line for some reason.

Comment: Okay nevermind. Just changed it to spaces. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

On your notepad++, go to Settings> Preferences > Tab Settings and Check "replace by space" making sure "tab Size" is set to 4. 
This has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, Go to Settings>>Preferences. In the dialog box that will appear select Tab Settings, check the 'Replace by space' checkbox. You can alter the number of spaces by clicking on the Tab space: 4 link (whereby the existing tab space is 4 spaces). Close the dialog box. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you dont see 'tab settings'  Under "Preferences", as myself, then you just need to look for.

Notepad++ > Settings > Preferences > language > Tab settings