# Python Script from Notepad++ Error in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs

I have a large library of python scripts that I wrote in Notepad++ and Pycharm, and I would like to start running them with Emacs. However, something about these files is causing a syntax error in Emacs.

As a minimum working example, I saved the following in Notepad++:

```
print('hello world')
```

Then, I open it in Emacs 22.3.1, and go to Python --> Start Interpreter. I type C-c C-c, and I get the following error in the interpreter screen:

```
File "/tmp/py110681cL", line 1
    print('hello world')
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This makes it look like there is an indentation it is reading at the beginning of the line, but I do not see it in the Emacs text editor window.  I tried cleaning up whitespace to no avail.

If I create a new file in Emacs and manually type the same code, it runs just fine following this procedure.

I'd rather not manually retype all of my pre-existing scripts, so how can I remove this phantom space? Google was not helpful...

UPDATE: Notepad++ was representing my new lines with [CR][LF]. Removing the carriage return in Notepad++ allowed it to run in Emacs.

Comment: In Notepad++ try `Encoding -> Convert to UTF8` and also `Convert to UTF8 without BOM` and try again in Emacs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried both, but got the same result. (When I opened it in Notepad++ initially, "Encode in UTF-8" was already selected. I tried converting anyway.)

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366499/notepad-indentation-messes-up can help. Has lots of votes and similar adjustment to settings in notepad++

Comment: Replacing tabs with spaces did not fix it.  HOWEVER, by showing the whitespace symbols, I found that the end of line was both a carriage return and a line feed. Removing the carriage return fixes the problem.  I guess I will have to find and replace \r in all my scripts in Notepad++ (unless there's a faster way).

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that notepad++ is using `\r\n` (CARRIAGE RETURN + LINE FEED) to represent newlines, and Emacs interprets the `\r` as an invalid indent (as it is whitespace).

To prevent this from happening in the future, you can go to `Settings -> Preferences... -> New Document -> Format (Line ending)` and select `Unix/OSX`. `\r\n` is the Windows way of representing newlines, and it is `\n` in Unix/OSX/Linux. (Old Mac is just `\r`).

To ammend the existing files, you can do:

```bash
find /path/to/py/files -type f -iname '*.py' -exec sed $'s/\r$//' "{}" +;
```

(Finds all `.py` files in `/path/to/py/files` and executes `sed $'s/\r$//'` on them (Replace all `\r`s which are followed by end of lines with nothing)