# Importing modules inside of modules in Python

Tags: python, import, menu, hierarchy

I'm trying to create a hierarchy of options.  I'm able to create the first list of options:

1. lemur
2. gorillas
3. chimps

if the user chooses option 1 for lemurs then I run the Lemur.LE() function cause I already imported the lemur module.  They are then presented with another set of options:

1. Brandy
2. Cigars
3. Shaving Cream
4. Choose a different monkey.

option 4 runs a break which sends them back to the first list. I'm trying to repeat actions from the first architecture so that I can have them choose Shaven.SC() by importing when the function Lemur.LE() is called, but if I place the imports before the function starts then I get a fatal crash at the beginning when I first import lemur, if I call them from within' the LE() function then I get a strange indention exception. Thoughts? Am I making this harder on myself then necessary?

P.S.

Okay here's the Code:

```
begin = int(raw_input("""Options 1-6"""))
    elif begin == 3:
    L.Leg()
    elif begin == 6:
        print "Goodbye"
        exit()

Level 2:

def Leg():
    begin = int(raw_input("""options 1-5"""))
    elif begin == 2:
        import LegacyWT
    else:
        print "Returning to Main Menu."
        break
```

Comment: @Béres: Almost right: *Post a **minimal** code example that reproduces the error* is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> get a strange indention exception. Thoughts? Am I making this harder on myself then necessary?

Indentation exceptions are almost always caused by mixing tabs and spaces in the same file.  If you are using a decent editor, you can set it to automatically convert tabs to spaces.  If you are not using a decent, stop it, and use a decent editor.

Comment: I'm using Notepad++.  If Python doesn't get along with it then I don't think its a problem with the editor not being decent.

Comment: @DJG: Notepad++ is certainly adequate for python.  Here's another Stack overflow question that will tell you how to take care of those pesky tabs:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/notepad-tabs-to-spaces

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are doing wrong without a code sample. In general import is a statement like any other and can be used in any scope. So:

```
def LE():
    ...
    if option == 'Shaving Cream':
        import Shaven
        Shaven.SC()
    elif option == ...
```

should work just fine.

Comment: `then` is not a Python keyword