# Notepad++ Automatic Detection of Python Tabs or Spaces

Tags: python, tabs, notepad++

I normally write code with tabs but many python libraries use spaces. Is there any way for Notepad++ to automatically detect how the file is formatted and have it automatically switch to using spaces when the file is already formatted that way?

BTW, I know there was already an [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/notepad-tabs-to-spaces) on how to change Notepad++'s tab format. But it would be better if it automatically changed based on the current file's formatting.

Comment: Side note: Python Tools for Visual Studio will automatically normalize spacing to be either tabs or spaces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you install the "Python Script" plugin for Notepad++, you can write code to automatically switch between tabs and spaces.

Here's how:

1. In the menu: Plugins -> Python Script -> Configuration, and set Initialization to ATSTARTUP. When Notepad++ starts, the `startup.py` script will run.
2. Find `startup.py` and edit it. On my PC its path is  `c:\Program Files\Notepad++\plugins\PythonScript\scripts\startup.py`, add the following code to `startup.py`.

The function `buffer_active()` is called every time when you switch tab, and `guess_tab()` checks whether the text is using tab indent or not. You can show the Python console to debug the code.

```
def guess_tab(text):
    count = 0
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        indents = line[:len(line)-len(line.lstrip())]
        if "\t" in indents:
            count += 1
    if count > 5: 
        return True
    else:
        return False

def buffer_active(arg):
    editor.setBackSpaceUnIndents(True)
    use_tab = guess_tab(editor.getText())
    editor.setUseTabs(use_tab)
    sys.stderr.write( "setUseTabs %s\n" % use_tab )

notepad.clearCallbacks([NOTIFICATION.BUFFERACTIVATED])    
notepad.callback(buffer_active, [NOTIFICATION.BUFFERACTIVATED])
```

This is only an example, feel free to make `guess_tab()` better yourself, maybe use a global dict to cache the result and speedup the callback function.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. This may be a problem with PythonScript. I don't see anything printed in the console when I switch tabs. Shouldn't I see setUseTabs?

Comment: I've just tried it, and it works perfectly!

speedplane: change "if count > 5" to "if count > 0".. maybe you've tried it on files with less than 6 lines with tabs in front of it?

@HYRY: why don't you post it over here? https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/forums/forum/1199074 ... it's a very handy script!

Comment: Got it working! I had to re-install the Python Script plugin from the plugin manager.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an improved version based on HYRY's answer :

- Works on the startup tab (when you launch notepad++ to open a file)
- Doesn't need a minimal amount of rows to trigger indentation detection. Indentation guess is based on the first encountered indented line.
- Keeps indentation defaults when indentation cannot be detected
- Very efficient, doesn't slow down Notepad++ when opening big files (tested on a 220 MB file, indentation detection takes only < 300 ms)

Available for download here : https://gist.github.com/vincepare/8a204172d959defb2122

```
import re
import time

def indent_guess_tab(text):
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        pattern = re.compile("^( {4,}|\t)")
        match = pattern.match(line)
        if (match):
            return True if ("\t" in match.group(1)) else False

def indent_auto_detect(arg):
    start = time.clock()

    # Get text sample
    maxLen = 500000
    len = editor.getTextLength()
    len = len if len < maxLen else maxLen
    sample = editor.getTextRange(0, len)

    # Indent set
    current_use_tab = editor.getUseTabs()
    use_tab = indent_guess_tab(sample)

    if (use_tab != None and use_tab != current_use_tab):
        console.write("Indent use tab switch (%s => %s)\n" % (current_use_tab, use_tab))
        editor.setUseTabs(use_tab)

    end = time.clock()
    console.write("Indentation detection took %s ms\n" % (round((end-start)*1000, 3)))

notepad.clearCallbacks([NOTIFICATION.BUFFERACTIVATED, NOTIFICATION.READY])    
notepad.callback(indent_auto_detect, [NOTIFICATION.BUFFERACTIVATED])
notepad.callback(indent_auto_detect, [NOTIFICATION.READY])
console.write("Automatic indentation detection started\n")
indent_auto_detect(None)
```

Comment: And here's another one that also detects the number of spaces (and is much shorter): https://gist.github.com/patstew/8dc8a4c0b816e2f33204e3e15cd5497e

Answer (score 1):

Nope!

You can always just change them (to *tabs*, of course) to suit your needs with Replace All (    , `\t`) in extended mode.

Comment: Or **TextFX > TextFX Edit > Leading spaces to tabs or tabs to spaces**, but I question the efficacy of Notepad++ plugins sometimes.

Comment: @BoltClock: Ah, thanks. I'm usually afraid to touch the TextFX menu :)