# Spyder Python indentation

Tags: python, spyder

I am using spyder IDE for python coding. I copied the code from some source,it works fine. But when I make edits in it indentation error occurs. There is always some mistake in the alignment of my edit and the other part of code. Code is quite large I can't re indent it.

Comment: Possibly a mix of tabs and spaces? If that's the case, you can download Notepad++ and use [convert tabs to spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/notepad-convert-tabs-to-spaces) to homogenize your indentations.

Comment: Use `spaces` rather then `tabs`, and don't mix both of these.

Answer (score 47):

In Spyder v3.0.0, go to Source --> Fix Indentation. That worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

In Spyder v5.3.3,
Also, go to Source --> Fix Indentation. That worked for me.