# Source code space mess

Tags: google-chrome, notepad++

I have my code perfectly tabbed in Notepad++, but it is a mess in the source code in Google Chrome.

[image: Google Chrome]
[image: Notepad++]

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't try fix this. It literally is the least worthwhile thing you will ever do. The indentation in the output makes absolutely no difference. Use the inspector if you want to review with nice indentation. Even if you can make the output nice now with flat HTML, it will be impossible once you move on to generating HTML with server-side code. *As long as your working code is formatted correctly, this is all that matters*.

Answer (score 0):

Replace all occurrences of a tab (`\t`) with two spaces (), or replace all occurrences of two consecutive spaces with a tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Tabs vs Spaces,

There is an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7471232/184201 for how to do that.