# How to keep the view format in notepad++ from simple notepad?

Tags: regex, notepad++, notepad

Been trying to get this one done for some time and couldn't find a solution.

The annoying issue I got is that when I open my x.txt notepad file everything is in line, organized, well arranged however when I do open it with notepad++ everything gets messed up. Here is a quick example (left notepad++/right notepad, same file) http://prntscr.com/9ypxcm

Some of the files get the same view format and style in both notepad and notepad++ (probably they were created originally in notepad++?) however some of my other text documents get really messed into notepad++ and I just hate simple windows notepad when it comes to text editing.

Would appreciate some help. Thank you

Comment: have you used a mixture of tabs and spaces to create that text?

Comment: You can convert tabs to spaces in notepad++ per this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-notepad

Comment: An image doesn't help much, as we can't tell anything about the content in them. In Notepad++, use `View->Show Symbol->Show White Space and TAB`. What's separating the columns of numbers, tabs or spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked for **How much spaces does a tab takes in both ?**.

> Notepad++ takes **4 spaces to constitute 1 tab**.
>
> Windows Notepad takes **6 spaces to constitute 1 tab**.

Therefore when a file which is first edited in Windows Notepad ( `6 spaces-tab` ) is opened in Notepad++, the tab is converted to 4 spaces reducing 2 spaces. That's why *everything gets messed up*

**Solution**

1) This is same file opened in two editors.

[image: Messed up in Notepad++. Okay in Windows Notepad.]

2) Now go as directed

> Settings --> Preferences --> Tab Settings --> normal.
>
> Uncheck the `Use default value.`
>
> Click on `Tab size`. A small input box will appear.Input `6` as value and press `Enter`.

[image: Setting custom tab value.]

3) The tabs are now properly formatted.

[image: Properly formatted.]

Comment: Thanks so much, this helped a lot. I had to change the tab size to 8 to get it right.

Comment: @Chris: My  pleasure. I got to know this feature for the first time. :-)