# How to supress error: Mixed spaces and tabs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I get this annoying 'error' message in `Vue.js` app.

```
error: Mixed spaces and tabs (no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs) at src/components/Landing.vue:388:2:
```

I'm wondering how can I suppress it?

Comment: Use an IDE like VS Code or WebStorm that doesn't include tabs at all and all tabs will be converted to spaces.

Comment: I'm used to sublime text, and don't want to change IDE just because of this stupid error.

Comment: Then set Sublime to replace tabs with spaces.

Comment: Yeah, this sorted it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86CMWVXdxDA though really did not respond the question.

Comment: The lint rules are in there for a reason, I answered how to fix the warnings, not ignore them.

Comment: What's the reason for that? We are not in python, so why the difference should matter?

Comment: @Babr *Consistency* of spaces/tabs is a code convention, which is important when sharing a codebase within a team [(1)](http://patrickwalters.net/why-coding-conventions-matter-for-a-team/) [(2)](https://scottdorman.github.io/2007/06/29/Why-Coding-Standards-Are-Important/). If you're swinging it alone (and have no plans otherwise), feel free to disable/enable any rules you want. :-)

Comment: for notepad++ users, see the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7471232/7468610

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That's an [ESLint error (`no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs`)](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs), intended to warn against using both space and tab for indenting code. *Consistency* of spaces/tabs is a code convention, which is important when sharing a codebase within a team ([1](http://patrickwalters.net/why-coding-conventions-matter-for-a-team/)) ([2](https://scottdorman.blog/2007/06/29/why-coding-standards-are-important/)). If you're swinging it alone (and have no plans otherwise), feel free to disable/enable any rules you want.

### Disable rule per project

You can configure ESLint to ignore that error in your entire project. The configuration is usually stored in `.eslintrc.js` in a Vue CLI generated project. Inside that file, edit the `rules` object to contain:

```
// .eslintrc.js
module.exports = {
  "rules": {
    "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 0, // disable rule
  }
}
```

### Disable rule per line

To ignore that error for a single line only, use an inline comment ([`eslint-disable-line no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs` or `eslint-disable-next-line no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs`](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments)) on that line:

```js
⋅⋅const x = 1
⇥⋅⋅const y = 2 // eslint-disable-line no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs

// eslint-disable-next-line no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs
⇥⋅⋅const z = 3
```

### Disable rule per section

To ignore that error for multiple lines of code, surround the code with `eslint-disable no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs` and `eslint-enable no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs` **multi-line** comments:

```js
⋅⋅const x = 1

/* eslint-disable no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs */
⇥⋅⋅const y = 2  // 
⇥⋅⋅const z = 3  // 
/* eslint-enable no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs */

⇥⋅⋅const q = 4  // ❌ error: mixed spaces and tabs!
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to `view option` then go to `indentation` and you will find `indent using space`. Your problem should be fixed. If it is not fixed then go to `convert indention to spaces`.

Answer (score 0):

You can install this plugin `@stylistic/eslint-plugin-js` with this command:

> **npm i -D @stylistic/eslint-plugin-js**

And then you need add this `'@stylistic/js/indent': ['error', 2]` and this `'@stylistic/js'` now your `eslint.js/json` should look like this.

```
 module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    '@stylistic/js'
  ],
  rules: {
    '@stylistic/js/indent': ['error', 2]
  }
}
```

For other information about this `plugin`, you can find from this site https://eslint.style/packages/js#install

Answer (score -1):

By fixing those code style issues.

That's an [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) rule violation. It has no impact on whether your code actually runs, but it warns you that your source code is not ideally formatted.

It means that in your code [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_(typesetting)) (which are invisible characters) you are using a mix of tabs and spaces.

It should be either one or the other. So make sure you always use *either* tabs or spaces but never both.

Most IDE's have options to convert tab to spaces or vice versa, to convert existing code so it complies with this rule.

Otherwise [@tony19's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52269222/1814486) has you covered.

Comment: There are actually good reasons to use both tabs & spaces in certain situations: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs