# Configure Notepad++ to convert tabs to *exact* number of spaces

Tags: notepad++

**How can I make Notepad++ convert my tabs into *exactly* 4 spaces regardless of position or context?**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/455037/1961815) explains the general way to configure Notepad++ to use spaces instead of tabs.  However, it still forces the spaces to adhere to the tab grid, meaning that if you're set to replace a tab with 4 spaces, it will actually replace it with ***up to*** 4 spaces and bring align it with the next column that is a multiple of 4.  **I do not desire this - I want exactly 4 spaces regardless of tab alignment.**

For example: If I have typed 6 characters on a line and press tab, it currently inserts 2 spaces instead of 4, bringing me to column 8 (because this is the next multiple of 4).

**How can I make it such that pressing tab does not take the tab alignment into account, and simply inserts 4 spaces no matter what?**

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. Tab stops are absolute, not relative by definition.

Answer (score 1):

You request to overwrite the intrinsic TAB functionality. Which is about strict alignment.

What you want is a keyboard shortcut that will insert (2,4,6...) spaces.

I suggest you :

1. Record a simple macro that will insert 4 spaces.
2. Give the macro name, for example `m4spaces`
3. Assign an available keyboard combination to macro `m4spaces`.

This way you do not disrupt the current TAB behavior, and extend behavior with your keyboard shortcut.