# Indentation error, nothing done wrong [LP3THW, 35]

Tags: python-3.x, indentation

After slightly altering an exercise from LP3THW, I started to receive an indentation error when running the script for a second time in Powershell: "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation".

I set the editor to show the indents and it does show some space mixed up with tabs, even though I consistently use tabs only when I type. I tried indenting those specific lines several times and it doesn't work (they end up showing as dots, as for space, instead of arrows, as for tab).

Am I doing something wrong...?

(I'm using Python 3.8 in Windows 10)

[(lines 9 to 15)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXw6v.png)

Comment: As the error notes, you're mixing tabs and spaces, which isn't good. Use software like a good IDE that's capable of fixing it the indentation, and set the tab key to emit spaces instead of a tab.

Comment: I never got this error until today and I only use tabs. I will try to change this setting and see if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I consulted the answer in
[Convert tabs to spaces in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037/convert-tabs-to-spaces-in-notepad?rq=1)
in order to change the settings for Tab.
Don't know what originated the error in the first place, but the script works now